# How to align GUI elements like this? Qt, C++

Tags: c++, qt

I need to align elements on GUI: actually, a single label, but at the specific position. I know how to use QGridLayout, QHBoxLayout, I know how to change the font to have the specified size. However, I don't know how to align the label like on this picture below. Any advices?

[image]

Comment: If specified sizes are absolutely fixed (picture quality is not enough for me to see some digits), then you don't need layout manager, I guess. You can place `QLabel` directly to the target `QWidget`, move it and resize. Smth like `QLabel *lbl = new QLabel(_wgt /* that's a pointer to your fixed widget */);` and `lbl->resize(...); lbl->move(...)`. Don't you?

Comment: why you've change picture to significantly different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the most direct, but hardcoded way.

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QLabel>
#include <QFont>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    QSize frameSize = this->frameGeometry().size() - this->geometry().size();

    this->resize(frameSize + QSize(250, 125));
    QLabel * label = new QLabel(this);// parenting instead of layouts
    label->resize(130, 32);
    label->move(60, 40);

    QFont f = label->font();
    f.setPointSize(16);
    label->setFont(f);

    label->setText("Sample");
    label->setFrameStyle(QFrame::Box);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{

}
```

Layouts and alignments are a much better solution, but if you really want to give numbers to everything...  Also look into using forms.  It makes "hardcoding" sizes and layouts a lot easier.

Hope that helps.

Comment: manually setting geometry? This is crappy approach, you have layouts and style sheets which are more flexible and less bug prone.

Comment: @MarekR  Agreed.  From the question, though, it sounds like the user has a homework assignment or something with "pixel perfect" requirements of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the proportions, but have it resizeable, you can use QBoxLayouts and the addStretch() method. Roughly you have a 1/2/1 proportion, so you first add a stretch with stretch 1, then your widget with stretch 2 and then another stretch with stretch 1. That would be for the horizontal layout, you would then take that layout and put it in a vertical layout with 1/1/1 stretches.

Answer (score 1):

If you know abut layouts and how to use them than great.

To tweak this after you have a layout you should use a [style sheet](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html). Here are some [examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html). You can set a style sheet on [QApplication](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#styleSheet-prop).

```css
QPushButton#buttonName {
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-left: 60px;
    margin-right: 60px;
    min-width: 130px;
    min-height : 32px;
}
```

PS. I know this is student homework :P

Comment: I know about style sheet method too. The point is, it seemed tricky at first, but turned out to be very simple. Anyway, thanks for your answer :) Even if it was a student homework (which is not, actually, its just some exercise to practice given by our teacher), notice that I asked only about the advice, not for the source code itself. Not my fault people gave the code.

Comment: I've seen today exactly same question in other place of Internet. Someone would like to pay for ready solution.